# 3 Conditions IFS not behaving as expected

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building a commission tracker at my work and I need to search a specific cell and produce 1 of 3 values (in a different cell) based on the text string that the cell holds.

Here is the logic:

- If cell is empty put error message in cell
- If cell contains "No Metrics" as the string, populate a 0 in the cell
- If cell contains any strings other than "No Metrics" populate 50 in cell

Here is my formula:

```
=IFS('Won Opportunities - Sales'!AQ26="", "SALES PERSON IS GARBAGE",'Won Opportunities - Sales'!AQ26="<>No Metrics",50,'Won Opportunities - Sales'!AQ26="No Metrics",0)
```

This works fine for empty cells and cells that contain "No Metrics" but gives back #N/A for anything else.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roy, you've got a syntax error.  Try this:

`=IFS('Won Opportunities - Sales'!AQ26="", "SALES PERSON IS GARBAGE",'Won Opportunities - Sales'!AQ26<>"No Metrics",50,'Won Opportunities - Sales'!AQ26="No Metrics",0)`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I was thinking its a simple syntax error, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: We ALL get "blind" to our own stuff occasionally, Roy. Glad to help shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives that tell the story as well:

```
=IF(A1="","SALES PERSON IS GARBAGE",IF(A1="No Metrics",0,50))
```

or

```
=SWITCH(A1,"","SALES PERSON IS GARBAGE","No Metrics",0,50)
```

Comment: Great to know. Thank you!